# How to resolve "Could not find a part of the path" when checking into TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, google-api, visual-studio-2017

Started to get the following error: 
`Z:\.NET Projects\JSConsultants\JSConsultants\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll: Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\.NET Projects\JSConsultants\JSConsultants\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.` when trying to check into TFS 2017 this morning. The only thing I added to my project was the Google API infrastructure.

Comment: Does the file actually exist on disk? Does it show in your pending changes window?

Comment: Not as 10.0.2. It is at `"Z:\.NET Projects\JSConsultants\JSConsultants\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"`

Comment: Is this a simple matter of editing the packages file to point to 10.0.3?

Comment: nm,... Packages.conf already point to 10.0.3

Comment: Is it shown in your pending changes? You will get this error when trying to checkin a file that no longer exists on disk. You will have to remove the pending change from your pending changes window.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Is this a bug?

Comment: OK,... so I had to go through and exclude 6 different duplicates (different versions)packages. What causes this?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. You tracked a file in your solution and then removed it from disk without updating the pending changes window. That results in an error.

Answer (score -1):

The error you mention happens whenever you have a file in your pending changes that no longer exists on disk. You have to go to your pending changes window and undo each of the changes that reference files that are removed.